# No Input while sorting a stack

Tags: arrays, sorting, struct, stack

There are 3 stacks - A, B, C

Stacks A and B are sorted (the number on the top of the stack is the biggest). Stack C is Empty Only 5 operation are allowed:

push, pop, top, is_empty, create

We need to write a function that receives the stacks A and B, moves all the numbers in stacks A and B to stack C and stack C must be sorted (biggest Number is on top).

I have the algorithm :

>

```
Compare top of A with top of B
```

Pop the least element and push to stack C

Repeat step 2 until any of the stack ( A or B) becomes empty

Move remaining elements from non-empty stack to C. Now you have all the elements in C  but in ascending order. (That is least element at top).

Move all the elements from C to A. (Contents in A are in descending order)

Move all the elements from A to B. (Contents in B are in ascending order)

Move all the elements from B to C.

And here is the CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX_MEMBERS 4
typedef struct
{
    int num;
}ITEM;

typedef struct
{
    ITEM a[MAX_MEMBERS];
    int top;
  } STACK;

void create_stack(STACK *s)
{
    s->top=-1;
}

int is_empty(STACK *s)
{
return s->top==-1;
}

 int is_full(STACK *s)
{
return s->top==MAX_MEMBERS-1;
}

ITEM pop(STACK *s)
{
    return s->a[s->top--];
}

void push(STACK *s,ITEM *item)
{
    s->a[++s->top]=*item;
}

ITEM top(STACK *s)
{
    return s->a[s->top];
}



void sort (STACK *a,STACK *b,STACK *c)
{
int i;
    ITEM y,x;
    while(!is_empty(a)||!is_empty(b))
    {

y=top(a);
x=top(b);

  if(&y>&x)
   {
    push(c,&x);
    pop(b);
   }
  else
    {
     push(c,&y);
         pop(a);

    }
}
if(!is_empty(a))
{
while(!is_empty(a))
x=pop(a);
push(c,&x);
}

else
while(!is_empty(b))
{
x=pop(b);
push(c,&x);
}

while(!is_empty(c))
{
x=pop(c);
push(a,&x);
}

while(!is_empty(a))
{
x=pop(a);
push(b,&x);
}

while(!is_empty(b))
{
x=pop(b);
push(c,&x);
}

for(i=0;i<MAX_MEMBERS-1;i++)
printf("%d",c->a[i]);
}

void main(void)
{
 int i;
STACK a,b,c;
ITEM x;
create_stack(&a);
create_stack(&b);
create_stack(&c);

 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
printf("\nEnter a number to insert for A: ");
scanf("%d",&x.num);
push(&a,&x);
 }

 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
printf("\nEnter a number to insert for B: ");
scanf("%d",&x.num);
push(&b,&x);
 }

    sort(&a,&b,&c);

}
```

I debugged the code and saw where is the problem .. 
it here :     if(&y>&x) 
It always give a "true" value for this boolean condition ..
even when     x

Answer (score 0):

Because you compare addresses of the variables, not variables itself

Comment: and how i can compare the values of the variables ?

Comment: By removing the ampersand.